# WiFi Text Services

Tags: sms, twilio, sms-gateway, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to come up with a solution to this situation:

Imagine you are in an area and you do not have any cell phone service but you do have Wifi.

The ask is to have a user that only has data to be able to text a number (via iMessage) and get a confirmation code in return.

The first tool I thought would be necessary for this would be Twilio - but it seems like Twilio only sends over standard SMS.

Are there any other tools out there anyone have used that would work in this idea? Something similar to Twilio but only ran on data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is something you can only do as the phone provider or network provider (using Three in the UK allows me to make phone calls over wifi with no phone signal, for example).

The two things you can do is either build yourself a native application that you can send messages to using [push notifications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify) or send messages to existing native apps, like [Messenger, Viber or Line](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/channels).